# How to get connection pool metrices of JDK native HttpClient?

Tags: java, httpclient, grafana

I am using JDK native HttpClient in my application. I want some insights into the http connection pool e.g. no of active connections with each of the downstream, idle connections etc. and create a grafana dashboard with it. I did not find any official doc for it. Is there a way to extract this info?